# How to set the required attribute on a hidden div when it's displayed?

Tags: javascript

I have a hdden div wit ha select inside it. I would like to set the required attribute when the div is displayed.

```
function showHide(elem) {
  if (elem.selectedIndex !== -1) {
    //get the divs to show/hide
    divsO = document.getElementById("frmRegister").getElementsByTagName('div');
    //hide the divs
    for (var i = 0; i < divsO.length; i++) {
      divsO[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    //unhide the selected div
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('div' + elem.value);
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementsByClassName(elems[i]).getElementsByTagName('select')[0].required = true;
    }
    prices();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName(elems[i])` doesn’t make sense. `elems[i]` is already an element, not a string to be used as a class name argument.

What you need is just `elems[i]` instead, so that line should be

```
elems[i].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].required = true;
```